# Regular Expression exclude pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract "create statements" from a PLSQL script.
I know this could be done with a Lexer/Parser, but I am trying to do this with JavaScript Regex.

Given a "script" with this content, I want to extract the different statements.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Cheopsregbp.SITE_OT AS

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION SITE_OT (
         p_site_list_id VARCHAR2
       , p_traductions TRADUCTIONS_MAP_ENTRY_CT := new TRADUCTIONS_MAP_ENTRY_CT()
      )
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELF.site_list_id := p_site_list_id;
    SELF.traductions := p_traductions;
    RETURN;
  END;

  STATIC FUNCTION convert_to_date(p_date_string in VARCHAR2, p_field_name_in in VARCHAR2, p_field_name_out IN OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE IS
  BEGIN
    -- function to convert string to date and keep track of which field we are converting => needed to produce error
    p_field_name_out := p_field_name_in; -- this will cause fieldName (declared in verify) to be updated before potential fail in next line
    RETURN cast(to_timestamp(p_date_string, Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.DATE_FORMAT) as date);
  END convert_to_date;

  STATIC FUNCTION convert_to_number(p_number_string in VARCHAR2, p_field_name_in in VARCHAR2, p_field_name_out IN OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    -- function to convert string to number and keep track of which field we are converting => needed to produce error
    p_field_name_out := p_field_name_in; -- this will cause fieldName (declared in verify) to be updated before potential fail in next line
    RETURN cast(p_number_string as number);
  END convert_to_number;

  STATIC FUNCTION from_json(p_json_object in BLOB) RETURN SITE_OT IS -- $$ref-ot-fromJson-BLOB
    l_clob CLOB;
    l_warning INTEGER;
    l_offset INTEGER := 1;
    l_csId INTEGER := nls_charset_id('UTF8');
    l_lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
    l_amount INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.lobMaxSize;
  BEGIN
    IF p_json_object IS NULL THEN
      RETURN null;
    END IF;
    dbms_lob.createTemporary(lob_loc => l_clob, cache => false);
    dbms_lob.convertToClob(  dest_lob     => l_clob
                            ,src_blob     => p_json_object
                            ,amount       => l_amount
                            ,dest_offset  => l_offset
                            ,src_offset   => l_offset
                            ,blob_csId    => l_csId
                            ,lang_context => l_lang_context
                            ,warning      => l_warning);
    apex_json.parse(l_clob);
    RETURN from_json(''); -- '' => root-path -- works with apex_json.g_values!
  END from_json;

  STATIC FUNCTION from_json(p_parent in VARCHAR2) -- works with apex_json.g_values!
  RETURN SITE_OT IS -- $$ref-ot-fromJson-CLOB
    l_arr_count INTEGER;
    l_parent VARCHAR2(2048 CHAR) := p_parent;
    l_api_error API_ERROR_OT;
    l_field_name Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.CHAR256;
    l_traductions TRADUCTIONS_MAP_ENTRY_CT := new TRADUCTIONS_MAP_ENTRY_CT();
    l_result SITE_OT;
  BEGIN
    IF p_parent IS NOT NULL THEN l_parent := p_parent || '.'; END IF;
        -- prepare list of traductions
        l_arr_count := apex_json.get_count(p_path => l_parent || 'traductions'); -- works with apex_json.g_values!
        IF l_arr_count > 0 THEN
            FOR i in 1 .. l_arr_count LOOP
                l_traductions.extend;
                l_traductions(l_traductions.last) := TRADUCTIONS_MAP_ENTRY_OT.from_json( l_parent || 'traductions['||i||']'); -- $$ref-fromJSONListItemFn
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
        l_result := SITE_OT( -- $$ref-fromJSONReturn
      p_site_list_id => apex_json.GET_VARCHAR2( l_parent || 'site_list_id'), -- $$ref-returnJSONField
      p_traductions => l_traductions
    );
    RETURN l_result;
  EXCEPTION -- $$ref-fromJSONExceptions
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        l_api_error := new API_ERROR_OT(Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.NO_DATA_FOUND, Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.HTTP_404, l_field_name);
        l_api_error.sqlcode := sqlcode;
        l_api_error.sqlerrm := sqlerrm;
        l_api_error.stacktrace := 'SITE_OT.verify';
        API_CORE_HLPR.add_error(l_api_error);
        RETURN NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        l_api_error := new API_ERROR_OT(Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.INVALID_DATA, Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.HTTP_400, l_field_name);
        l_api_error.sqlcode := sqlcode;
        l_api_error.sqlerrm := sqlerrm;
        l_api_error.stacktrace := 'SITE_OT.verify';
        API_CORE_HLPR.add_error(l_api_error);
        RETURN NULL;
  END from_json;

  MEMBER PROCEDURE verify(p_parent IN VARCHAR2 := null) AS -- $$ref-ot-verify
    l_params Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.CHAR1024;
    l_parent Cheopsregbp.API_CONST_HLPR.CHAR256;
    l_api_error API_ERROR_OT;
  BEGIN
    IF p_parent  IS NOT NULL THEN
        l_parent := p_parent || '.';
    END IF;
    -- key field does not have to be present. POST => new => no PK yet; PUT => PK is in URL!
    -- If PK value is specified in body then it should be checked against URL param value though (in business logic)!
    /** traductions is REQUIRED!! */
    IF SELF.traductions IS NULL THEN
       l_api_error := new API_ERROR_OT('REQUIRED', 400, l_parent||'traductions');
       l_api_error.sqlerrm := 'REQUIRED' || ':'|| l_parent||'traductions';
       l_api_error.stacktrace  := 'SITE_OT.verify';
       API_CORE_HLPR.add_error(l_api_error);
    END IF;
    -- validate children (if any)
    /** verify all traductions */
    IF SELF.traductions IS NOT NULL AND SELF.traductions.COUNT > 0 THEN
        <<verify_fields_loop>>
       FOR i IN 1 .. SELF.traductions.COUNT LOOP
          SELF.traductions(i).verify('traductions['||(i-1)||']'); -- $$verifyChild (UI zero-based)
       END LOOP verify_fields_loop;
    END IF;
  END verify;

  MEMBER PROCEDURE add_traductions(p_traductions_map_entry IN TRADUCTIONS_MAP_ENTRY_OT) IS -- $$OOT.ADD2
  BEGIN
      SELF.traductions.extend;
      SELF.traductions(SELF.traductions.last) := p_traductions_map_entry;
  END add_traductions;

END;
/

GRANT EXECUTE ON SITE_OT TO Cheopsregbp;
/
```

I Would have to get 2 statements:

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY...
2. GRANT EXECUTE ON SITE_OT TO...

I was thinking to scan the text multiple times for the different known statements.
The second one is easy, but the first one is quite hard.
The first command is almost the whole text. It ends just above the second text.

I can't start with 'CREATE OR REPLACE...' and end with 'END;', because END; can be part of another statement too.

So actually I need to find the text CREATE OR REPLACE...END; but skip any intermediate

'BEGIN...**END**;'
'IF...**END** IF;'
'LOOP...**END** LOOP;'

And to make it harder, any of these 3 statements can have a "label" before the ';'
So 'LOOP...**END** LOOP some_label; should be skipped as well.

I am able to find all BEGIN...END blocks without stopping on intermediate END IF or END LOOP parts with regex `BEGIN\s+.*?\s+END(?!\s+IF|\s+LOOP).*?;` but I cannot seem to get it right for the complete CREATE...END; statement.

I came up with regex `CREATE(BEGIN\s+.*?\s+END(?!\s+IF|\s+LOOP).*?;|.*?)END` but that stops again on the END of the first begin block.

Comment: Is the '/' on the next line always there by itself after the real 'END;' statement?  Can you do something simple like `CREATE.*END;^$/^`?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not guaranteed :-/

Comment: @mvermand are tabs/spacing at the start of each line consistent?

Comment: This is also not guaranteed :-/ I do not think there are easy patterns like simply searching for a unique ending sequence without interpreting the intermediate.

Comment: Javascript doesn't allow balanced groups or recursion in regex, so you'll likely have to create a parser. I'm not the downvoter, but there's a vote for "close - needs more focus" - someone must have felt that there wasn't enough information to appropriately answer your question. To be fair, it isn't the easiest to understand, maybe you could work on the wording or add formatting to your question to make it more clear?

Comment: If the CREATE statement is at the start of the line and the accompanying END statement is also at the beginning of the line and intermediate variations do not occur at the start of the line, try `^CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY.*\n(?:.*\n)*END;$` https://regex101.com/r/x98hGc/1/

Answer (score 0):

I only tested this against Java regex, not javascript, so YMMV

Try `(CREATE(BEGIN\s+.*?\s+END(?!\s+IF|\s+LOOP).*?;|.*?)END?).*`

I.E. put a "greedy" qualifier on the END;